# Does OpenCL workgroup size matter in the OS X CPU runtime?

Tags: macos, opencl, grand-central-dispatch

In the OS X OpenCL CPU runtime, the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/Performance/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH113-SW7) indicates that "Work items are scheduled in different tasks submitted to Grand Central Dispatch".  That would seem to indicate that workgroups are essentially a no-op, and you should shoot for (number of work items) = (number of hardware threads) with (number of workgroups) being irrelevant.  However, on other implementations, there are low-cost switches between items in the same workgroup via essentially coroutines (setjmp and longjmp), which would make it much less expensive to schedule more work-items (since you avoid a full OS-managed thread context switch between items), which in turn would make it easier to reuse code between CPU and GPU targets.  According to "Heterogeneous Computing with OpenCL", AMD's CPU runtime does this, and I vaguely recall some documentation indicating the same is true for Intel's CPU runtime.

Can anyone confirm the behavior of workgroups in the OS X CPU runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated later in the document (see the Autovectorizer section), workgroup size on CPU is linked to autovectorized code.

The autovectorizer aggregates several consecutive work-items into a single kernel function calling vector instructions (SSE, AVX) as much as possible.

Setting the workgroup size to 1 disables the autovectorizer. Larger values will enable vector code when available.  In most cases, the generated code is able to efficiently use all the CPU resources.

In all cases, OpenCL on CPU runs on a small number of hardware threads.

**Update**: to answer the question in the comments.

It works usually quite well. Start with a "scalar" kernel and benchmark it to see the speedup provided by the autovectorizer, then "hand-vectorize" only if the speedup is not good enough. To help the compiler, avoid using "if", and prefer conditional assignments and bit operations.

Comment: That's interesting.  I was not aware of this.  How good is it?  Isn't it better to do it yourself?  I mean use float8 and, for example, operate on eight pixels at once and submit n/8 jobs?  Then you know for sure it's doing what you want.

Comment: I mean instead of having a kernel for each pixel with a number of jobs = num. pixels instead have a kernel which operates on 8 pixels at once (using float 8) and num_jobs = num_pixels/8.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I conclude that the documentation is incorrect or misleading and it's work groups, not work items, that are the unit of parallelism / unit of dispatch to GCD.  The autovectorization documentation states that it "Packs work items together [and] generates a loop over the entire workgroup" which would indicate that items are no longer distinct tasks once they're work-groupified, and that would be more in line with the way the Intel & AMD CPU runtimes function as well.  It's unclear whether that is true with autovectorization disabled.